# Changing a default Zsh completion function

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I noticed that tab completion for the `source` command in Zsh tries to complete a LOT of files. Maybe everything in $PATH? I tried using a blank `.zshrc` file to make sure it wasn't anything in there.

```
ubuntu% source d
zsh: do you wish to see all 109 possibilities (16 lines)?
```

I did find this file that seems to control that: `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Zsh/_source`

```sh
#compdef source .

if [[ CURRENT -ge 3 ]]; then
  compset -n 2
  _normal
else
  if [[ -prefix */ && ! -o pathdirs ]]; then
    _files
  elif [[ $service = . ]]; then
    _files -W path
  else
    _files -W "(. $path)"
  fi
fi
```

If I change the line in that last "else" statement from `_files -W "(. $path)"` to `_files`, it works the way I want it to. The tab completion only looks at files & directories in the current dir.

It doesn't seem like altering this file is the best way to go. I'd rather change something in my `.zshrc` file. But my knowledge of Zsh completions is a bit lacking and the searching I've done thus far hasn't led me to an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe everything in $PATH?

Yes, that is correct. It offers those, because `source` will search your the current dir *and* your `$PATH` for any file name you pass it.

To apply your change without modifying the original file, add this to your `.zshrc` file *after* calling `compinit`:

```sh
compdef '
if [[ CURRENT -ge 3 ]]; then
  compset -n 2
  _normal
else
  _files
fi
' source
```

This tells the completion system to use the inline function you specified for the command `source` (instead of the default function).

Alternatively, to see file completions for the current dir only, you can type

```sh
$ source ./<TAB>
```

Comment: It looks like I'm not calling `compinit` in my `.zshrc` file at all. How should that be called?

Comment: Ahh, never mind. I just put `compinit` before that block and it works. Thank you!

Comment: If you're using, for example, Oh-My-Zsh or Ubuntu, then `compinit` will already get called automatically and you don't need to call it manually.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k
Seems like it's called automatically there as well.

Comment: I don’t think so: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/search?q=compinit+&type=

Comment: Ahh, well this still works w/out calling compinit in my .zshrc file.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu/Arch Linux

Comment: Like I said, on Ubuntu, `compinit` gets called automatically: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/zsh/-/blob/debian/debian/zshrc#L106

Comment: Oh thanks. I read that as "Oh-My-Zsh on Ubuntu" and not "Oh-My-Zsh or Ubuntu."